# How to find out whether whcih user who had run the datastage job last time?

Tags: unix, logging, datastage

Someone ran wrong job with wrong inputs which caused a lot of problems and now my managers want me to find out the user name of that person.

So is there any way in logs or somewhere else where I would be able to find out the last user name who ran this job?

Comment: Yes you can check the logs in director

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the job log and in the environment variables entry (2nd entry in the job log) you'll see a field called ISUSER (if my memory is correct). That property will give the name of the person who executed your DataStage job.